# What is the best practice to cache multiple partial views in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

We are developing an application in MVC. We have three pages in our application.

The left pane changes, as a place holder for partial view. After every post back we change the partial view (by storing the partial view name in view bag).

The right pane(dynamic content from db) of the page remains consistent through out the navigation. We have "Index" view with right pane as the dynamic content. To persist the dynamic content from db in right pane through out the post back, we store it in session and read it again.

Is this the ideal way to handle the problem? Can this be implemented in more efficient way, and if so how?

Comment: facebook implement a big pipe technique, here is an example with asp.net mvc http://jmperezperez.com/tutorial-how-to-implement-bigpipe-using-asp-net-mvc-part-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the ideal way to handle the problem?

That architecture is not the most ideal way to handle the problem.

> Can this be implemented in more efficient way, and if so how?

[Improving Performance with Output Caching](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs) and [Understanding Caching in Asp.Net MVC with example](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/4R5c050113-Understanding-Caching-in-Asp.Net-MVC-with-example.html)

Both of these links describe using the [OutputCacheAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to cache view (including partials).  This attribute/feature is already built into the framework.  Already tested.  Already includes many features of when to cache, where to cache, how to determine when the cache should be purged. I recommend you don't try to reinvent the wheel.